# PHP - Saving dynamic fields to the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Im wondering if someone could help me out with a little issue im having.

I have some code which enables a user to click a button and it will create a additional file input box ... The amount of times they can click this is unlimited, so realisticly they can add unlimited images to their profile.

The problem im having is im not sure how to go about saving that information to the database, usually i would add a row for a file input and store the name, but as there can be unlimited amounts of filenames, im not sure how i would go about saving it.

Could anyone out there give me some suggestions on how they would do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store additional pieces of information in a separate table. It only needs 2 fields, `data` and `user_id`, Then for each additional input, you would store the `data` and the user's unique `user_id`. To retrieve the data, just filter using the `user_id`.

Comment: Except for it is nearly always better to have primary key, so add auto_increment `id` if you are planning to refer to that images individually.

Comment: True, but this was stripped down to the heart of the issue.

Comment: Hmmm thats an interesting way of tackling it .... What about serializing it and putting it in a field on teh same row as the details?

Comment: @BigJobbies the problem with serializing it is that, as you mentioned, you don't know how many extra input items there are. You really don't want to run out of space trying to cram it in one field. Also, it is more efficient to let the dbms fetch the data, than to have a program sort it out.

Comment: Agreed with @BigJobbles, sometimes I used exactly that way he described in comment. For example, to store filenames of multiple thumbnails or previews.

Comment: Ahhhh ok ... Thanks for clearing that up .... Ive decided to cap the number of dynamic fields to 10 .. so when the script hits 10 inputs it says that they cant have anymore

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's doing using 2 tables and foreign keys. One table with users(user) (id, name, ...). Second table with photos of users(user_photo) (id, user_id, photo_path, ...). Foreign key will be created between user.id and user_photo.user_id with cascade delete/update.